# JQuery DropDown spacing problems

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

Im having problems getting some text in a dropdown menu under each other. Any idea how to fix it?

Here is the HTML and C#

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li>
     <p class="MenuOverskrift">
        <a href="#">Produkter</a>
     </p>

     <ul>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Standard_Panel" runat="server" Text="" />
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

string standard_Menu = "";

        foreach (Products group in Products.GetEvereGroup(connection))
        {
            standard_Menu += "<li>" +
                "<p>" +
                group.GroupName +
                "</p>" +
                "<ul>";

            foreach (Products product in Products.GetProductsByGroup(group.GroupID, connection))
            {
                standard_Menu += "<li>" +
                    "<p>" +
                    "<a href=\"_" + product.Link + "\">" + product.ProductName + "</a>" +
                    "</p>" +
                    "</li>";
            }

            standard_Menu += "</ul>" +
                "</li>";

            lbl_Standard_Panel.Text = standard_Menu;
        }
```

And here is the CSS

```
#Menu_Standard
{
position: relative;
left: 550px;
width: 100px;
}
#Menu_Standard ul li ul li p
{
    color: #9c8b5c;
}
    #Menu_Standard ul ul ul
    {
        right: 100px;
    }
        #Menu_Standard ul li ul li a
        {
            color: #9c8b5c;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: medium;
        }
            #Menu_Standard a
            {
                color: #9c8b5c;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: x-large;
            }

ul.dropdown ul
{ 
visibility: hidden;
position:relative; 
z-index:1;
width: auto;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul
{ 
visibility: visible;
background-color: #373741;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

and here is a picture of the problem
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

fixed some of the problem by changing visibilty: hidden; to diplay: none;

but the problem still occour while hovering
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when `visibility: hidden` property is set for an element that element behaves as its opacity is 0, use `display: none` instead.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix my other problem?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard have you replaced all `visibility` properties with `display`?

Comment: yea, but the new result happens when i hover over "Smykker" and the second list appears

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard I can see #Menu_Standard there which has been set to 100px from right, if that is the part of the menu, it pushes the other elements to the bottom, if you don't want to see space betwen the main manu elements use `position: absolute` for will be shown elements.

Comment: well it didn't help setting the position of #Menu_Standard to absolute, but it did help doing it on ul.dropdown ul ^^